# Which compact camera supports time lapse photography natively?

Tags: timelapse, camera-recommendation, compact-cameras, intervalometer

I'm fascinated from time lapse photography. 
I've started using my DSLR but after a while, I start thinking that I don't want to "kill" my shutter. So I would like to buy a good compact camera, with electronic shutter and with the option to shoot continuously with a specified interval.

Which cameras support this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Photo.SE is not well-suited to maintaining lists of products supporting *x*-feature.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is *Interval Timer*. For most cameras this means choosing the number of shots, an interval and a start delay. Some cameras also allow multiple shots at each intervals but I have only seen that in high-end models.

To find which compact camera supports this, use the [Camera Search](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php) page at Neocamera (FD: The digital camera site I've been running since 2005). The trick is to select *Interval Timer* from the *Refine Results* column after searching for cameras with your other criteria. Here are [compact cameras with interval timer](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=compact&intervaltimer=1). By default this returns *current* cameras but you can expand the search to discontinued ones too.

From the above results, there are 11 models currently. Two of them particularly stand out from the rest, the [Panasonic ZS100 which I reviewed here](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/panasonic/zs100/review). It has a larger 1" CMOS sensor with 10X optical zoom. Also the [Ricoh GR II](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/pentax/grii) which has an APS-C sensor with a fixed 28mm-equivalent prime.

Comment: You could probably make it a little more clear regarding your association with Neocamera.

Comment: Looks like Neocamera doesn't include GoPro, or other brands of action cameras, many of which have a timelapse mode.

Answer (score 1):

The [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) (Canon Hack Development Kit) can be used with any of the supported Canon point and shoots and scripts to enable intervalometer shooting for time-lapse sequences.

See: http://lifehacker.com/5942229/unlock-the-secret-pro-features-of-your-canon-point-and-shoot-camera-with-chdk